# Peer authentication failed for user "odoo"

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

I'm on Odoo 9, I have an issue when lunching odoo server `$odoo.py -r odoo -w password`, the `localhost:8069` doesn't load and I get an error on terminal "Peer authentication failed for user "odoo"".

I already created a user "odoo" on postgres.
When lunching `$odoo.py` I can load the odoo page on browser but I can't create database (as default user).

It was working and i already created database but when I logged out I couldn't connect to my database account anymore.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change your pg_hba.conf configuration.
This error means that you are using peer authentication, so you need to change it for md5 or something that suits you.

You can find more information here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

If you are connecting locally you will need to change the following entrance from

local   all             all                                     peer

to something like this :

local   all             all                                     md5

Answer (score 6):

This helped me.

- sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

then add

- local all odoo trust

then restart postgres

- sudo service postgresql restart

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but upper results are not working for me.Well this will definitely work.
You can see this django [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264003/peer-authentication-fails-with-postgressql-in-celery-task).

Apparently there are multiple ways for authentication with postgresql.

So,if your Postgresql user is different from your linux user then one easy way is to add `--db_host` to `localhost` which is `"127.0.0.1"`:

```
.odoo-bin -r "pg_user" -w 'pg_pass' --db_host "127.0.0.1"
```

If you feel any problem in this,Tell me i will elaburate further

Comment: `--db_host '127.0.0.1'` saved my day